# Why keydown doesn't let us enter text when used with inline expression

Tags: angular, typescript, keydown

I'm trying to use keydown event with an inline expression like this -

```
public isWorking: boolean;

<input (keydown)="isWorking = true" />
```

But it's not letting me enter any text into the textbox. But if I use a method such as -

```
<input (keydown)="inputChanged()" />

public inputChanged(): void {
  this.isWorking = true;
}
```

it works fine.

Where as, when I use `keyup`, it works fine with the inline expression, as stated above.

What's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Seems to be working for me in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8vezeq?file=src/app/app.component.html) in Chrome.

Comment: I'm too using Chrome.